# Looking for a java web compiler that supports realtime input without needing a sign up

Tags: java

I'm teaching a programming lesson to some kids relatively soon. Ideone is great, but the way it handles stdin isn't as engaging as I'm hoping for, and it makes programs like [this](https://ideone.com/2djoa1) not work very well. I'm looking to minimize "setup time" since it's a short series of lessons.

Is there a java web compiler that doesn't require an account and also has an interactive console?

(Program from ideone link above. Would be written differently with an interactive console.)

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String password = "socketwrench";
    boolean grantAccess = false;
    System.out.println("Please enter your password.");
    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        String attempt = in.nextLine();
        if (!attempt.equals(password))
        {
            System.out.println("Access denied.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Access granted!");
            grantAccess = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (grantAccess)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome back.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("System lockout!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile Java, and most other popular languages, online at this website.

[Compile Java Online Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

[Compile Java 8 Online Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php)

[Compile Other Languages Online Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm)

Comment: Thanks, that first link seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!